# Unable to set kafka spark consumer configs

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, kafka-consumer-api, spark-structured-streaming

Me using spark-sql-2.4.x version of with kafka client.

Even after setting the consumer configuration parameter
i.e.
    max.partition.fetch.bytes & max.poll.records

it is not being set properly and showing default values as below

```
Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession
                      .readStream()
                      .format("kafka")
                      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", server1)
                      .option("subscribe", TOPIC1) 
                      .option("includeTimestamp", true)
                      .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
                      .option("max.partition.fetch.bytes", "2097152") // default 1000,000
                      .option("max.poll.records", 6000)  // default 500
                      .option("metadata.max.age.ms", 450000) // default 300000
                      .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
                      .load();
```

**It is still showing in logs as below while starting the consumer:**

```
[Executor task launch worker for task 21] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig - ConsumerConfig values:
        auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
        auto.offset.reset = none
        check.crcs = true
        client.id =
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        enable.auto.commit = false
        exclude.internal.topics = true
        fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
        fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
        heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
        interceptor.classes = null
        key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
        max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
        max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
        max.poll.records = 500
        value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
```

what is the correct way to set this ?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#kafka-specific-configurations):

> Kafka’s own configurations can be set via DataStreamReader.option with
>   kafka. prefix, e.g, stream.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",
>   "host:port"). For possible kafka parameters, see [Kafka consumer config](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#newconsumerconfigs)
>   docs for parameters related to reading data, and [Kafka producer config](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs)
>   docs for parameters related to writing data.

I believe you need to add "kafka." to your options, like:

```
.option("kafka.max.poll.records", 6000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use property

```
.("maxOffsetsPerTrigger","6000")
```

to maintain the micro-batch size. It will fetch maximum 6000 offsets every micro-batch